# Last message in conversation for preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `Conversation` model which `has_many` `messages`. I want to pull all the conversations for a user and display the last `message` preview to the users. I am doing this as follows:

`Conversations_controller`:

```
def index
  @conversations = Conversation.includes(:messages)
                               .get_seller_conversations(@seller)
end
```

`Conversation` model:

```
def self.get_seller_conversations(seller)
  @conversations = seller.conversations
                         .includes(buyer: :user)
                         .joins(:messages)
                         .where(messages: { only_for_buyer: false })
                         .distinct
  new.sorted_conversations(@conversations)
end


def sorted_conversations(conversations)
  conversations.sort_by { |c| c.messages.last.created_at }
  .reverse
end
```

`index.json.jbuilder` -> view

```
json.array!(@conversations.reject { |c| c.messages == [] }.map do |c|
  x = c.messages.last
  { ...
    ...
    preview: x.content ? x.content[0..100] : x.attachment_url }
end)
```

So I have to pull all the messages over here to sort the conversations and show the preview of the last message. Is there a way I can only pull the last message for every conversation and thus make this more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a relationship in your `Conversation` model to its last message:

`has_one :last_message, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, source: :message`

And then in your search instead of doing `Conversation.includes(:messages)` you do `Conversation.includes(:last_message)`

Comment: So in that case, what do I do with the `where condition in the model` because if that last messages turns out to be `only_for_buyer` then the conversation won't have any message right?

Comment: You can add the condition in the relationship `has_one :last_message, -> { order(created_at: :desc).where(only_for_buyer: false) }, source: :message`

Comment: Yeah I did the same thing; is there a way to sort the conversations according to the `created_at` date for the `last_message` too?

Comment: When you do the `includes(:last_message)` then you should be able to do `.order('messages.created_at')` after if you want to sort on that field.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I was trying to do `.order('last_message.created_at')` but of course what you're saying makes sense

Comment: I have a follow-up though; if I use `.order('messages.created_at')` then it pulls the messages for the conversations again rather than using the `last_message` so it sort of defeats the purpose

Comment: According to `bullet` I should add an `includes` for `messages` over here now because I'm sorting on the basis of created_At` for `messages`

Comment: `source: :message` didn't work for me so I did it as `class_name: "Message"` instead, but I don't think that should affect the sort

Comment: Well, in that case I'll do the sorting on ruby like in your `sorted_conversations` method, but instead of on all messages use the last_message. If you pass your loaded conversations that include the last message, this won't trigger new queries because the info is already there.